# notepad ++ regex help

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

I want to find the following pattern in notepad ++

Ping statistics for 192.168(regex to capture everything after the last character)

Comment: How can there be anything after the **last** character?

Comment: Ping statistics for 192.168.(.*) worked for me. Hope this helps someone else

Comment: Post that as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
^192.168.[\d]+.[\d]+$
```

Not perfect, but it should be enough for your case.
It accepts 192.168.21314.1252151

Edit:

```
^192\.168\.[\d]+\.[\d]+$
```

To avoid matching 1920168012937

Comment: You should at least escape the dots or you'll match 1920168098, too.